# What's wrong with this mysql query? (Whmcs)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

This query is taking a lot of time to load in php application.In fact, it is not loading at all.
There are about 17k entries tblinvoices.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tblinvoices` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
  SELECT * 
  FROM `tblinvoiceitems` 
  WHERE `tblinvoiceitems`.`invoiceid` = `tblinvoices`.`id` 
    AND `type` IN ( 'Invoice' ) 
) AND `status` = 'Unpaid' 
  AND `userid` = '19830'
```

Is there anything I can do on server side (Mysql configuration) to make this query run faster?

Looking forward to your thoughts

Comment: Do you have an index on `status` or `userid`? Does `tblinvoiceitems` have an index on `invoiceid`?

Comment: Did you try an explain plan using a tool such as mySQL Workbench or sqldeveloper ? Also, you should avoid the `*` operator in the `not exists` (this will get all columns, while you are only checking for existence, you may as well simply `select null` here).

Comment: @NoDataFound I think (hope) that MySQL ignores the column list when a query is used in `EXISTS`.

Comment: This is from a web app called whmcs, and the source code is encoded with ioncube loader. I am not able to modify the query.
Thanks for the input

Comment: @Barmar: I don't know if mysql optimize this (it should probably), but at  which part ? eg: does it compile the subquery first, and replace '*' by list of columns then when executing it sees that it is unneeded, or does it see that the subquery is in not query and '*' is unneeded ? I don't know (and I'm less used to mysql than oracle, which does not help :)).

Comment: Please provide the explain plan for the query. Run it with "explain <your query here>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tough question to answer as there are numerous variables (you mention PHP) and we don't know what size server instance you are running let alone what other services etc.

17k is a very small number of records to not run but you are going to encounter plenty of bottlenecks down the road as is.

The first step would be to remove PHP from the equation.  Just try in MySQL CLI.

Have you tried to run the same query on a test database with a much smaller dataset?

Since your app is encoded it makes it very difficult to normalize your database but you can still run EXPLAIN on the queries and providing you have access to the database you can add and remove indexes as you need.

Try adding the following indexes...

```
CREATE INDEX idx_invoices_user_status ON tblinvoices(status,userid);
```

And...

```
CREATE INDEX idx_invoiceitems_invoiceid_type ON tblinvoiceitems(invoiceid,type);
```

I would be surprised if indexing is the issue but worth a shot...

Comment: ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'status' used in key specification without a key length
Any idea? I don't know much about SQL

Comment: You might want to remove status from the index or if you can change the type of status it really shouldn't be BLOB.  Use varchar with a len of the max len of status...

Comment: I would hazard a guess that your types are all messed up given that whoever designed the database didn't even bother to normalize it.  This could be your precise issue - data types with no indexing...

Comment: Hello the second one fixed it for me, now it's instantaneous

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM tblinvoices i 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tblinvoiceitems ii
                  WHERE ii.invoiceid = i.id AND ii.type = 'Invoice'
                 ) AND 
     i.status = 'Unpaid' AND
     i.userid = '19830';
```

You want indexes on `tblinvoices(userid, status, id)` and `tblinvoiceitems(invoiceid, type)`.